# T-SQL query with funny behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Let's say you have the following two tables:

**X Table**

**X_ID** **Y_ID_F** **X_Value**

```
1     1     Q
2     1     G
3     1     T
4     2     W
5     2     K
...
```

**Y Table**

**Y_ID** **Y_Value**

```
1     A
2     B
...
```

You want to query only those properties whose Y parent's value is A and update them so you write a query as follows (I realize there is a better query but bear with me):

```
UPDATE X set X_Value = 'O' 
WHERE X_ID IN
(
select distinct X.X_ID FROM X
INNER JOIN Y ON X.Y_ID_F = Y.Y_ID
WHERE Y.Y_Value = 'A'
)
```

I previously thought that this would do what it seemingly says : Update the rows of the X table where the joined Y table's Y_Value = 'A'.  However it seems that the X.X_ID causes all rows in the X table to be updated, not just the ones you'd think the WHERE clause restricted it to.  Somehow that X.X_ID causes the query to completely ignore the attempt of the where clause at restricting the set of updated rows.  Any ideas on why?

**EDIT:
I think it may have something to do with the way the tables in the database I am querying are associated and not as simple as the example I tried to equivocate it to.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never had luck with sub-selects in an UPDATE statement.  Instead, try something like the following:

```
UPDATE X SET X_Value = 'O'
FROM Y
WHERE Y.Y_ID = X.Y_ID_F
  AND Y.Y_Value = 'A'
```

Comment: This is how I write my T-SQL normally, however because I had a pre-existing query already written out I used it in a sub-select and expected it to behave as it was written.  I've always understood the sub-select to parse first but maybe I am incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't make any sense to me either, so I tried it. After running the update statement, the contents of table X looks like this:

```
X_ID   Y_ID   X_VALUE
1      1      O
2      1      O
3      1      O
4      2      W
5      2      K
```

In other words, the results I expected. Are you sure there isn't something else at work here? I did notice a minor anomaly in your example query: A reference to 'X.Y_ID_F' in the join condition where I would expect to see just 'X.Y_ID'. I assumed it was just a typo.